# Points at which a function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

$f=\frac{1}{z^5-1}$

$z=1$ ofcourse makes it non-holomorphic.

What other z's would make it non-holomorphic?

Is it only $z=1$ ?

Comment: Hey, you quit fast learned how to write in latex, good job. As tag add"complex-analysis" anyway

Comment: thank you. i like the fancy-ness of this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z^5-1=0$ has $5$ roots, the fifth roots of 1:
$$
z=e^{\tfrac{k\,\pi}{5}\,i},\quad 0\le k<5.
$$ Only one of them is real.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you!